# Python Error: Couldn't read from RWops

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm trying to make a small music player with tkinter, and pygame, by loading a file and then playing it. Everything works fine if I place the file-name into

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('filename.mp3')
```

But if I try to open the file with

```
file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
```

and I browse to the file and click open, I get an error which says

```
python.error: Couldn't read from RWops
```

Any clues onto what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`askopoenfile` returns a handle to an open file. If you want a file *name*, call `askopenfilename` instead.