# Can I pass a list to PyGame Music?

Tags: python, pygame, audio-player

Win 10/64bit/3.5:

I want to pass a list of .mp3s from within a variable (**mp3Fin**) to **pygame.mixer.music.load()**. Is there a way to do this? PyGame does work when I load separately. I've only been learning programming/python for the last couple weeks and am new to stackoverflow, so sorry if I left anything out.

**Last Edit** Here is the latest code as it should be, properly formatted/indented. It is still getting an error, but the error has changed to something related to 'Rwops'. Only found a few links off bing about Rwops. Will delete the previous code because I don't think they're helpful anymore.

**Code:**

```
if catChow == cat1[0]:
        print("Welcome to SoCha's music player.")   
        def get_files(directories):
            mp3Pre = []
            for root, directories, files in os.walk(directories):
                for filename in files:
                #Joins the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
                    filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    mp3Pre.append(filepath) #Adds to the mp3PreParse variable above.
            return mp3Pre
        mp3Post = get_files("C:\\Users\\SoCha\\Music")
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load([s for s in mp3Post if s.endswith(".mp3")])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

**Rwops Error:**

```
Welcome to SoCha's music player.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SoChaOS.2.0.py", line 38, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load([s for s in mp3Post if s.endswith(".mp3")])
pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops

***Repl Closed***
```

This is the last edit I'm making on this original post.

Comment: Just to be clear (since we don't have the entire file here) `pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3Fin[1])` is on line 41 of your program, right?

Comment: Yep, it is. 41 is the last line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mp3fin` is a string. Why are you indexing it? When you call `split()` it returns an array, which you print, and then throw away.

In the last line `pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3Fin[1])` you're splicing the string and taking the second character, which is a ':'.

You should probably just call `pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3Fin)`

---

> I want to pass a list of .mp3s from within a variable (mp3Fin) to
>   pygame.mixer.music.load().

`mp3Fin` isn't a List. mp3Post is the list of files found in your directory. Each individual file is in `mp3Fin` as the for loop iterates. Try:

```
for mp3Fin in mp3Post:
    if mp3Fin.endswith(".mp3"):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3Fin)
```

---

You can try passing the list to `load` buy using the following:

```
mp3Post = get_files("C:\\Users\\SoCha\\Music")
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load([s for s in mp3Post if s.endswith(".mp3")])
```

Comment: 'In the last line pygame.mixer.music.load....which is a...' I see that now. I was using the print to just check on it, but I confused myself. Still, I'm going to try rewriting it exactly as you suggested and see if that helps, if I made one mistake I may had made others. bbiaf.

Comment: I didn't have my idents lined up properly (they were supposed to be nested as part of 'if catChow'. I lined them up and now I'm getting a proper error. 'Welcome to SoCha's music player.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SoChaOS.2.0.py", line 38, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load([s for s in mp3Post if s.endswith(".mp3")])
pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops' The **RWops** is a new one for me, and Bing only returned 3 results, 1 of which is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792314/python-error-couldnt-read-from-rwops). **Bad formatting. This site hates me**

Comment: @SoCha I read the documentation for `pygame.mixer.music.load`. It only takes a filename or a file object. You cannot pass it a List like I showed in the last part of my post. Are you trying to mix multiple tracks together?

Comment: Yes. I saw that same doc but I just assumed file object stood for variable/list and tried anyway smh.<br/> This isn't vital at all. I just wanted to make my own beginner's proj. I had tried a few other mp3 modules, but none of them worked. I'll go ahead and add them one by one to my code the way others have done, unless you have a better suggestion. If you do have a suggestion, I just prefer it to play in the console, that's all. Either way, thanks for your help, @Swoogan.

Comment: @SoCha I no longer understand what you're trying to accomplish. I thought I resolved the error in your original submission.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `mp3Fin.split()` does not modify `mp3Fin` in place - `mp3Fin` stays a string!

So when you get to line 41, `mp3Fin[1]` is getting the character at position 1 of `mp3Fin`.  That's where the ":" in the error comes from, `C:/...`.

Try sending it the string directly

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3Fin)
```

Gotta be careful with those functions!

Comment: I had it like you suggested originally, but it still wouldn't play (though it didn't crash). I updated my original post to show everyone. I was just using the print to keep a check on whether or not the info was in mp3Fin.

Comment: @SoCha admittedly, I don't have an environment to test with right now - I'm just sort of eye-balling it.  It looks like the strings are all correct, are you sure that `.load` is working correctly?  I'm not familiar with `music-player`, but if it's supposed to take file paths in, and those file-paths all exist on your system, it seems like this would be the solution.